# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Permanently disable on screen keyboard

Tags: 18.04, onscreen-keyboard

Does anybody know how to get rid of the on screen keyboard for good please?
It's disabled in the Universal Access but each time a text entry element is touched on the touch screen back it comes like a dose of STD.
I have this on multiple devices running different flavours of 18.04.X and it's extremely undesirable.

Seems to go away if I plug a physical keyboard in but I don't want to do that.